# Usando Apollo con múltiples endpoints de GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, expo, apollo

Necesito utilizar múltiples esquemas de GraphQL, actualmente tengo instalado

---

**expo: sdk 42
"@apollo/client": "^3.4.11",
"apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
"graphql": "^15.5.3",**

Mientras utilizo un solo esquema todo funciona bien:
Declaración de un solo esquema

> App.js

```
import { ApolloProvider, ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: `${serverBaseUrl}/client/graphql`,
  });


const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        /**@todo datos del headers*/
      }
    }
  });

const client = new ApolloClient({
   link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
   cache: new InMemoryCache(),
   credentials: 'include'
});

<ApolloProvider client={client}>
 /**@todo declaraciones generales*/
```

> Realizando un query Example.jsx

```
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

  const E_QUERY = gql`
  query{
      example(sortBy: { field: "updatedAt", order: DESC }){
        _id
      }
  }
`;

const { loading, data } = useQuery(E_QUERY , {    
    fetchPolicy: "network-only",
  });
```

Todo bien por ahora,

> pero cuando agrego múltiples esquemas no me da error ni nada, solo se
> queda cargando solo
>
> App.js

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.split(
      operation => operation.getContext().clientName === "adminGQL",
      authLink.concat(httpLinkAdmin), 
      operation => operation.getContext().clientName === "agentGQL",
      authLink.concat(httpLinkAgent), 
      operation => operation.getContext().clientName === "client",
      authLink.concat(httpLinkAgent), 
    ),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    credentials: 'include'
  });
```

> Example.jsx

```
const { loading, data } = useQuery(EXAMPLE_QUERY , {    
    fetchPolicy: "network-only",
    context: { clientName: 'client' }
  });
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda de antemano

Comment: El primer error detectado es que ApolloLink.split solo puede realizar una comparación y solo tiene dos posibles casos (true o false) por lo que no se puede agregar  más de dos url, entonces como sera para agregar más de 2 url??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer error detectado es que ApolloLink.split solo puede realizar una comparación y solo tiene dos posibles casos (true o false) por lo que no se puede agregar más de dos url, entonces como sera para agregar más de 2 url??

> ApolloLink.d.ts

```
 static split(test: (op: Operation) => boolean, left: ApolloLink | RequestHandler, right?: ApolloLink | RequestHandler): ApolloLink;
```

Partiendo de este punto nos queda la solución de la siguiente forma

```
 const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.split(
      operation => operation.getContext().clientName === "adminGQL",
      authLink.concat(httpLinkAdmin), 
      authLink.concat(ApolloLink.split(
        operation => operation.getContext().clientName === "agentGQL",
        httpLinkAgent, 
        httpLink
      ))
    ),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    credentials: 'include'
  });
```

Quizás no sea la mejor solución, pero fue la que pude ser capaz de construir. Por lo que nuevas sugerencias o soluciones pueden ser bien recibidas