# TypeError: this.currentObservable.getCurrentResult is not a function (appsync + apollo-client)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, appsync

Tengo, un problema con una configuración de un cliente appsync en un componente react donde voy a usar el hook userQuery. He leído y en algunos casos comentan que problema de incompatibilidad con el apollo-client, que en mi caso tengo la versión: ^3.4.10. EN este caso necesito pasar en cliente directamente en el compomente porque ya tengo configurado otro cliente con el ApolloProvider en el index.

Este es el componente:

```
import React from "react";
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import AWSAppSyncClient, { AUTH_TYPE } from "aws-appsync";

export const GET_PERROS = gql`
   query MyQuery {
   getPerros {
   id
   name
   }
  }
 `;

 const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
   url: process.env.REACT_APP_URL,
   region: process.env.REACT_APP_REGION,
   auth: {
     type: "API_KEY",
     apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
   },
   disableOffline: true,
  });

 function Perros() {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_ASSETS, {
  client,
 });
  if (loading) return <div>Loading....</div>;
 return <div>Perros</div>;
 }

 export default Perros;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si realmente quieres utilizar dos clientes en la misma aplicación te recomiendo que [mires esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483897/usando-apollo-con-m%C3%BAltiples-endpoints-de-graphql), tenía el mismo problema y esta fue la forma de solucionarlo, ya que estas duplicando el client y obtienes esos problemas

Comment: Luego solo tienes que especificar el contexto al que te quieres referir
`const { loading, data, error, refetch } = useQuery(XXXXX_QUERY, {
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
    variables: { id: id },
    context: { clientName: "******" },
  });`